# ReactJS: Rendering chunks of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Setup is es6 class:

```
export default class Gallery extends Component {
  addPhotos() {
    let data = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]; // array of objects
    let dataChunks = chunk(data, 2); // returns array of two arrays [[{}, {}, {}],[{}, {}, {}]]

 // now here is where I am stuck. I want to:

  return dataChunk[0].map((photo) => (
    <PhotoComponent key={photo._id} photo={photo} />
  ));

 // wait 500ms and then add 3 more photos to the gallery (essentially throttling the loading)

  return dataChunk[1].map((photo) => (
    <PhotoComponent key={photo._id} photo={photo} />
  ));
```

Ideally, I am able to load 3 photos and then add the next 3 photos after 500ms.

As a bonus, having a loading component in between...

Thoughts?

What I have tried:

1) Using state to store the array. The problem seems to be rendering the array and changing it can cause a stack overflow problem.

2) Using a for loop with setTimeout... for some reason, the component props become undefined.

Comment: Run a `setTimeout` that changes the state with `this.setState` and you have some flag in the state that helps you determine what to render.

Comment: after 500 ms you want to replace the first 3 images or add new 3 images ?

Comment: @zerkms Can you give an example of what this would look like render and state and method

Comment: @MayankShukla I want to add 3 more images.

Comment: `state` would have `numberOfPhotos` property, with `3` set by default, and `this.setState({ numberOfPhotos: 6 });` done on timer. `render` method would take the `this.state.numberOfPhotos` value and render the corresponding number of photos. And you don't need chunks at all.

Comment: Okay, so, what does the render look like? `{this.addPhotos()}` and then in my component method `addPhotos() { let currentNumber = this.state.numberOfPhotos; for loop using number to return... the map of each item... I'm lost... at the end of the method setState({ numberOfPhotos: this.state.numberOfPhotos + numberUpdated })`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could write the answer out with your method and render call because I'm not sure where the setState should happen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintain a `state` variable that will check whether to `render` next part of `array` or not, and use timeout to change the status of that variable, it should work, Write it like this:

```
export default class Gallery extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state(
            renderNext: false,
            data: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
        )
    }

    _renderFisrtPart(){
        let data = this.state.data, arr = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length/2; i++){
            arr.push(<PhotoComponent key={data[i]._id} photo={data[i]} />)
        }
        setTimeout(()=>{this.setState(renderNext: true)}, 500);
        return arr;
    }

    _renderSecondPart(){
        if(!this.state.renderNext) return;

        let data = this.state.data, arr = [];
        for(let i = data.length/2; i < data.length; i++){
            arr.push(<PhotoComponent key={data[i]._id} photo={data[i]} />)
        }

        return arr;
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this._renderFisrtPart()}
                {this._renderSecondPart()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach, using `setTimeout` inside the `componentDidMount` method. You could also wrap it inside a Promise and chain `addData` down with `then`.

```
export default class Gallery extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.addData = this.addData.bind(this);

    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Don't know if you're getting your data via props
    const data = this.props.data || [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}];
    const chunks = chunk(data, 2);

    this.addData(chunks[0])();
    setTimeout(this.addData(chunks[1]), 500);
  }

  addData(data) {
    return () => this.setState({
      data: [
        ...this.state.data,
        ...data,
      ],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.data.map(photo => <PhotoComponent key={photo._id} photo={photo} />);
  }
}
```

Comment: i think it should be `data: [
        ...this.state.data,
        ...data
      ],` ???

Comment: Yes, fixed it. Thank you! :)

Comment: awesome dude, really nice structure +1 :)

Comment: @OleBläsing Okay, I decided to try this first, as it was closest to my original. So, the data is not ready by `componentDidMount()` hook, just consoles to an empty array. I had to move the call into `componentDidUpdate()` but now the data returns as an array of objects. Problem now is the stack overflow created by the hook being called, state being changed, and then hook being called etc... but I think this can work if setup a bit different... ideas?

Comment: You do not need to use `componentDidUpdate`. The state should be filled, after the `componentDidMount` method executes. Why do you need the filled state before? You could set your first chunk in the constructor, but there would be no benefit, if you not use it.

Comment: @OleBlasing Okay, when I use `componentDidMount()` I try to get the data from mongodb, but I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` When I console log data, it returns `[]`. However, when I console log data in the `componentDidUpdate()` hook, I get an array with all the data... The data only gets called when the user clicks a certain category. I need that click event to get the right data... so I have to wait for the update. But this results in the stack overflow problem...

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your MongoDB fetching method. You really should'nt use `componentDidMount` for this purpose. Try to fix your data fetching in `componentDidMount` or use a fetching component and wrap it around your Gallery component.

Comment: Ah meant componentDidUpdate in first occurence. :)